# Nginx alias not working

Tags: php, nginx, alias

I have a location block for which I define a different alias and I want its `index.php` file to be server from this same directory. The problem is Nginx is not serving the index file with the alias, but rather trying to find the file in the root dir (and it does not exist).

Config:

```
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    upstream php {
        server unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
        server_name my.domain.com;

        root /var/www;

        location / {
            alias /var/www/site/;
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }
}
```

So the root should point to the `site/` directory inside the root (`/var/www`), but the file trying to be served is `/var/www/index.php`:

`2014/05/21 15:41:19 [error] 9591#0: *190 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary     script: /var/www/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: my.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:666"`

Instead I expect the file to be served from `/var/www/index.php`.

Comment: What's the reason to have the same alias and root? Also, what's in fastcgi_params?

Comment: Sorry they are not the same, I fixed it. `fastcgi_params`is https://gist.github.com/ranisalt/b0eb02dc07f8d23649d1

Comment: What's the reason of the `alias` in `location /`? [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) is just a replacement for the location, it's not the `root`.

Comment: Lots of locations have different root folder, I use alias since some of them do not match the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx `location`s are exclusive. As soon as you leave location nginx forgets all context. In you case, last item in `try_files` is internal redirect so nginx forgets about alias and goes to `/index.php` which matches to `location ~ \.php$` with `root /var/www` inherited from server block.

I would simply change `root` directive to `root /var/www/site`, but if you really want to stick this cumbersome way, just change your `try_files` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /site/index.php?$args`.